# Are Alolan Oricorios based on real world Sunbirds?

Tags: pokemon

Are Oricorios based on Sunbirds?

This is a picture of a variation of Sunbird

[image]

This is a picture of just one variant of the Alolan Oricorios

[image]

They both come in multiple colors and both seem to drink nectar from flowers

[image]
<sub>(source: [bulbagarden.net](https://cdn.bulbagarden.net/upload/thumb/3/39/Baile_Style_Oricorio.png/250px-Baile_Style_Oricorio.png))</sub>

[image]

Are Oricorios based on sunbirds or another type of bird?

Answer (score 4):

[Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Oricorio_(Pok%C3%A9mon)) suggests the [Hawaiian Honeycreeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaiian_honeycreeper) as a possible inspiration:
[image]
Since the Alolan region is heavily based on the Hawaiian Islands, this seems the most likely possibility, but ultimately is still speculation (as with most Pokémon inspirations). Similar to Darwin's finches the honeycreepers have a variety of bill shapes to fill various ecological niches, which could be why there are different forms of Oricorio native to each island. Each form of Oricorio is of course also based on a different dance style, with the forms' names also coming from their individual dance styles.

Comment: +1 Why not bolster the speculation by reaching out to the author(s) of the game or cartoon or other media where the Oricorios firt appeared?